# Compiler: ORA-04082 (old and new refs not allowed), but E no such refs

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I thought I'd write an Oracle "table level" TRIGGER to avoid calling MERGE for every inserted row.
The compiler doesn't report any syntax errors, but it does issue the following error report:

> ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
>
> *Action:  Remove any new or old references

But here's the thing: There are *zero* references to **old** and **new** pseudo-rows!
(One might guess there is an internal source-to-source rewrite happening, and the error is about that hidden code.)

**Question:**

I could ask "How do I fix this code to appease the compiler?" but I'd *much prefer* to understand what's going on *under the hood*, so I can avoid this in the future.  (There is no way to view the rewrite, I assume.)

**Here's the trigger code**

```
create or replace trigger remember_old_prop_part2
  after insert on old_props_queue
  begin
    merge into event_extra dest
      using (select event_key, property_name, string_value 
             from old_props_queue) src
      on (    dest.event_key = src.event_key
          AND dest.property_name = src.property_name)
      when matched then
        update set string_value = :src.string_value
      when not matched then
        insert (event_key, property_name, string_value)
        values (:src.event_key, :src.property_name, :src.string_value);
    -- once merged, nuke the queue
    truncate table old_props_queue reuse storage;
  end;
```

**Here's the table that it triggers on**

```
create table old_props_queue
  ( "EVENT_KEY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PROPERTY_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STRING_VALUE" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    CONSTRAINT "PX_OLD_PROPS_QUEUE" PRIMARY KEY ("EVENT_KEY", "PROPERTY_NAME") DEFERRABLE );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " There are zero references to old and new pseudo-rows! "

The error is misleading. What it is objecting to are those colons when you reference the subquery: `:src` should just be `src`.

Once you fix that you will have to look at that TRUNCATE. We can't include DDL statements in a trigger, because DDL issues implicit commits and we can't have commits in triggers. Easiest solution would be to use DELETE instead.